# toggle dom elements with ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to toggle some dom elements in a dashboard using ng-if.

My html looks like:

//Buttons

```
<div>
<button ng-click="showDiv('div1');"></button>
<button ng-click="showDiv('div2');"></button>
</div>
```

//Content

```
<div ng-if="div1" class="div-1"></div>
<div ng-if="div2" class="div-2"></div>
```

//inside my controller:

```
    $scope.div1 = true;
    $scope.div2= false;
    $scope.showDiv = function(element){
       if($scope.element = 'div2'){
         $scope.div2 = true;
         $scope.div1 = false;
       }
      }
```

Actually the value assignments for div1 and div2 work initially, but the function is not working properly.

I am fiddling around for a while but I don't find a solution...some help would be great.

Thanks, Hucho

Comment: there is no `$scope.element` just `element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use element, which is your parameter

```
 $scope.showDiv = function(element){
       if(element === 'div2'){
         $scope.div2 = true;
         $scope.div1 = false;
       }
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.div1 = true;
    $scope.div2= false;
    $scope.showDiv = function(element){
       if(element === 'div2'){
         $scope.div2 = true;
         $scope.div1 = false;
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div>
<button ng-click="showDiv('div1');">DIV1</button>
<button ng-click="showDiv('div2');">DIV2</button>
</div>
<div ng-if="div1" class="div-1">TEST1</div>
<div ng-if="div2" class="div-2">TEST2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the demo. The hint with the element is very good and solves a part of my problem. However - what I do not understand is: If you click div1-button, Test1 element should not change - but acutally Test2 is shown? Why does that happen?

Comment: because you are making div1 to false and div2 to true

Comment: I don't get it. I call showDiv in button "DIV1" with 'div1'; the if-condition should not react in this case and change the bools...

Comment: One further question: I don't want to call showDiv() hardcoded with 'div1'. Is it possible to get the id or content of the element by an angular expression and call my function with that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **ng-class** and toggle the values accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the proposal - but with ng-class - if I am right - the element is not removed but onyl hidden...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
//view 
<button ng-click="toggleCustom()">Custom</button>
        <span ng-hide="custom">From:
            <input type="text" id="from" />
        </span>
        <span ng-hide="custom">To:
            <input type="text" id="to" />
        </span>
        <span ng-show="custom"></span>

//controller
$scope.custom = true;
        $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
            $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
        };
```

Comment: good proposal too, but if I use ng-hide, I will have to load all elements although I don't need them right now...maybe I think about it.